# Can Struts 1.x Resource Bundles be placed elsewhere than the classes directory?

Tags: struts, struts-1

**This is for Struts 1.x** (I'm using 1.3.10).

I've noticed that Struts is unable to pick up resource bundles in the `ApplicationResources.properties` file if it is *not* placed somewhere in the *default* classpath (e.g., `com.abc.SomePackage`).

For instance, if I put the `ApplicationResources.properties` file in a custom folder `/WEB-INF/strutsResources` and configure the struts-config.xml thus:

`<message-resources parameter="/WEB-INF/strutsResources/ApplicationResources"/>`

I've [read](http://www.learntechnology.net/content/struts/message_resources.jsp) that the resources need to be on the classpath so I've also tried adding the `/WEB-INF/strutsResources` folder to the classpath. It still does *not* pick up the resource keys.

I've double-checked that the `strutsResources` folder *is* actually deployed to the server (I'm using Glassfish v3), so the file is there, it's just not being parsed.

P.S.

1. If you're wondering why I'm trying to do this, I just wanted to organize my code a little better ("better," IMO). Since the `ApplicationResources.properties` file is not really a class, I wanted to place it in a resources folder by itself.
2. I've checked that placing the ApplicationResources file in a package in the src directory works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the answer is yes. You can play some interesting games by [configuring a custom `className` and/or `factory`](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/userGuide/configuration.html#a5.2.2_Message_Resources_Configuration) and get messages however you want (including from a database) and so on. This allows you to customize *whatever* you want*.

I agree the resources aren't a class, but putting them on the classpath is a common practice, and allows resources to be loaded as a resource, e.g., from inside a jar. I'm sympathetic, but I'd leave it as-is.

*Like reversing all the text; a fun prank to play on your co-workers and QA department.

Answer (score 0):

Its best leave it on the classpath.

It's stadard practise to include properties files on the classpath, especially if you're planning on packaging it up in your WAR/EAR. You're keeping it under WEB-INF so you gain no benefit from moving it off the classpath, and you'll just confuse other developers who have to work on the project and you've had to put a hack in to make this work.

If you want to keep your files external to your deployable WAR/EAR then that's a valid reason for not using the classpath. Typically this will require some configuration as part of your deployment to specify where the file is to reside.

For example specify the location using

1. a JVM argument (e.g. -Dprops.file=/config/myapp.properites)
2. lookup from a JNDI resource
3. use a PropertiesFactoryBean if you're using the Spring framework (I
   use Spring's ApplicationContext with Struts 1 MVC)
4. read properties from a database writing your own
   ApplicationPropertiesDAO class that initialises itself durnig your
   applications bootstrap process (e.g. Spring application contact,
   Servlet in web.xml, Listener in web.xml, etc)